# How to create ranking from most, to least popular number Javascript/ jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get data from the rest api that displays 5 random numbers from array, and I've made it display another every 10 seconds in an unordered list.
I would like to see a ranking displayed in another ordered list. 
Ranking should be sorted from most, to least popular number.

This is my code:

```
function generateRandomNumbers(){   
var feedback = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',  
        url: "http://localhost:3000/random-numbers"
    }).success(function(data){
        setTimeout(function(){generateRandomNumbers();}, 10000);
        $('#random-numbers').append('<li class="list-group-item">' + data.data + '</li>');
    });
  }
 $(function(){
    generateRandomNumbers();
  });
```

Someone can help me :) ?

Comment: If you can get the numbers into an array you can use array.sort. Can you show how you're getting the numbers (what the output of the API is)?

Comment: Please add the output of the `http://localhost:3000/random-numbers` in your question.

Comment: {
  "data": [
    10,
    8,
    3,
    5,
    9
  ]
}